# How can you remove matrix rows in Matlab based on some criteria?

Tags: matlab, matrix

In Matlab, how can I remove spesific rows from a matrix I require? If for example I would like to remove all rows from a matrix which contain a spesific value (like 0 or NaN)?

Comment: what do you mean by remove?

Comment: Hey, be removing I mean erasing the entire row which contains a spesific value :) If I have a 3-by-3 matrix A = [1 0 0; 2 5 4; 7 8 8]; And I want to remove all rows which include number 7, then my reduced matrix would be A = [1 0 0; 2 5 4];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have `A`

```
A = [1 2 3;4 5 0; 7 8 9; 10 NaN 12]

A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     0
     7     8     9
    10   NaN    12
```

Then, you can choose the rows as follows:

```
any(isnan(A'))

ans =

     0     0     0     1
```

To delete those `NaN`-containing rows, you can do:

```
A(any(isnan(A')),:) = []

A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     0
     7     8     9
```

You can choose `0`-containing rows by `any(A' == 0)`. If you want all elements to be `0`s or `NaN`s, then you can use `all` instead of `any`.