# Delete values from different columns depending on a value from a specific column

Tags: matlab, dependencies, delete-row

I have a double variable with 3 columns. Sometimes, in the second column I obtain the value zero. In case it happens I want to completely erase that line. For instance:

```
12346 67 89

1245 0 765

56 0 99

19862 8 675
```

What I would like to get:

```
12346 67 89

19862 8 675
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally done using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html):

```
A = [12346 67 89
     1245  0  765
     56    0  99
     19862 8  675];

mask = (A(:,2) ~= 0);
ans = A(mask, :)
```

The same but by deleting elements from the original array:

```
mask = (A(:,2) == 0);
A(mask, :) = []
```

A very similar question: [How can you remove matrix rows in Matlab based on some criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14811423/2379410)